# CKeditor inline instance not loading

Tags: ckeditor

Can someone help regards an issue I have with the CKEditor inline. I cannot get the toolbar to appear? Have a look at this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rr2m49zn/4/

Clicking on 'Edit me' should bring up the tool bar

HTML

`<body><table><tbody><tr><td contenteditable="true">Edit me</td></tr></tbody></table></body>`

JS

```
                if ( typeof CKEDITOR == 'undefined' )

                CKEDITOR.add

                CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceCreated', function ( event ) {


                    var editor = event.editor,
                        element = editor.element;

                    // Customize editors for headers and tag list.
                    // These editors do not need features like smileys, templates, iframes etc.
                        // Customize the editor configuration on "configLoaded" event,
                        // which is fired after the configuration file loading and
                        // execution. This makes it possible to change the
                        // configuration before the editor initialization takes place.
                        editor.on( 'configLoaded', function () {

                            editor.config.toolbarGroups = [
                            { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
                            { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
                            { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
                            { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
                            '/',
                            { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
                            { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
                            { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
                            { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
                            '/',
                            { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
                            { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
                            { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
                            { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
                            { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
                        ];

                        editor.config.removeButtons = 'Source,Save,NewPage,Preview,Print,Templates,Cut,Copy,Paste,PasteText,PasteFromWord,Undo,Redo,Replace,Find,SelectAll,Scayt,Form,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,CreateDiv,Blockquote,BidiLtr,BidiRtl,Language,Anchor,Image,Flash,Table,HorizontalRule,Smiley,PageBreak,Iframe,Maximize,ShowBlocks,About,Placeholder';

                        } );


                } );

            }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: ... Doh! - sorted - contenteditable="true" needs to be assign to a div to <td> tag

Comment: Please delete the question if it's not relevant anymore.